# Habilitar campos a partir do preenchimento de um campo anterior

Tags: jquery, ajax

Preciso fazer um formulário que, para habilitar um campo seja obrigatório o preenchimento de um campo anterior.

Sendo que irá existir uma paginação entre uma pergunta e outra (próximo ou anterior).

Tem como fazer isso no Ajax?

Estou usando **PHP** e acho que isso pode ser feito com **AJAX** ou **JQuery**, mas não sei como fazer isso.

Comment: você pode usar o atributo `disabled` nos campos com a função `attr` do jQuery para habilitar os campos sempre que eles trocarem de dados... `$("#nome").change(function() { if($(this).val().length > 0) { $("#nascimento").removeAttr("disabled"); } });`

Comment: Obrigado Leonardo apesar de não gostarem que agradeçam nesse foram. rs  <br> Eu não tenho conhecimento em jquery e ajax mas vou conseguir. Eu não me expressei bem, mas vou usar select e/ou radio buttom. Vc teria algum tutorial?
Obrigado.

Comment: Olá @fabricio_wm tem alguns exemplos bem fáceis aqui: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_disabled

Comment: Sobre o jQuery, este site ajuda muito, tem o referencial completo e vários exemplos: http://api.jquery.com/removeattr/

Comment: Quanto o select e radio button, acredito que você não terá problemas com eles, o atributo disabled funciona com estes também

Comment: Leonardo. Funcionou com o input, mas eu quero habilitar um link com aparencia de botão (uso bootstrap). tem alguma dica?
Obrigado.

Comment: Sinto que estou quase, lá.
Fiz assim:
<label class="radio"><input name="ativo" type="radio" class="form_1" value="S" onclick="if(document.getElementById('titulo').disabled==true){document.getElementById('titulo').disabled=false}"/>Sim</label>
                                   <label class="radio"><input name="ativo" type="radio" class="form_1" value="N" onclick="if(document.getElementById('titulo').disabled==true){document.getElementById('titulo').disabled=false}"/>Não</label>
<button id="titulo" disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" href="test.php" >teste</button>

Comment: Quando eu clico, carrega a mesma página.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15314/discussion-between-fabricio-wm-and-leonardo-bosquett).

Comment: você pode fazer o seguinte: <button class="" onclick="javascirpt:document.location = 'yourlink.php'" />

Comment: Esta acontencendo a mesma coisas.
Eu clico no radio button e habilita e o button e quando clico, carrega a mesma página mudando de http://localhost/dashboard/questionario_posvenda/teste.php?ativo=N para http://localhost/dashboard/questionario_posvenda/teste.php?ativo=S

Comment: Consegui de outra forma.
<button id="titulo" disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"><a href="../../dashboard/questionario_posvenda/alert1.php">teste</a></button>

Comment: Pensei que tinha funcionado, mas não funcionou.
Dessa forma, alem de alterar a cor da font, o link carrega mesmo se clicar no botao desabilitado.

Comment: Consegui.
coloquei o button com type="submit e no form coloquei o action passando o link da próxima página.
Obrigado.

Comment: <form action="teste.php" method="post">
   <select>
<option name="ativo" value="--" onclick="if(document.getElementById('avancar').disabled==false){document.getElementById('avancar').disabled=true}"/> --</option>
                                <option name="ativo" value="FUNCIONARIO1" onclick="if(document.getElementById('avancar').disabled==true{document.getElementById('avancar').disabled=false}"/>FUNCIONÁRIO 1</option>
   <select>
<button id="avancar" type="submit" disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" >Avançar</button>
</form>

@LeonardoBosquett Pode me ajudar? select ruim

Comment: poderia abrir uma nova questão? estamos fugindo deste contexto e código em comentários vai complicar nossa vida :)

Comment: Já estou abrindo.
Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz um exemplo no JSFiddle [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/luizz/t9qfH/), usei [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/)  e [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), numerei as etapa com o atributo 'data-etapa', e o(s) campo(s) obrigatório(s) o atributo 'required';

- JQuery

Assim as funções 'prev' e 'next' relacionadas a 'data-next' e 'data-prev'(atributo);

A validação e chamada na função 'next', passando a etapa ativa e validando.

*A validação deve ser feita no PHP !*

Comment: Obrigado @Luizz.

Answer (score 0):

Com ou sem Bootstrap o que eu costumo fazer nesse tipo de formulários é fazer tudo na mesma página, recorrendo somente ao PHP.

E com o `onChange` alterar a ação do formulário.

```
<form action="">
...
   //mudando de página
   <input name="input1" onChange="this.form.action='novaPagina.php'">

   //se pretender ficar na mesma página
   <input name="input2">

   <?php
   if (isset($_POST['input2']))
   {
       //verificação que pretender, como por exemplo adicionar um campo:
       echo "<input name='input3'>";
       ...
       //ou preencher um campo 
   }
   ?>
...
</form>
```

Se não ficar esclarecido amanhã melhoro a resposta.